# Django - Remove add new record from form widget>

Tags: python, django

I have created a form widget that is automatically adding a add new record section at the top of the form, which i do not want to be there. can someone tell me how to disable this? I just want to display the variables not the add form.

forms.py

```
class TemplateVariablesWidget(forms.Widget):
    template_name = 'sites/config_variables.html'

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        sc_vars = ConfigVariables.objects.filter(type='Showroom')
        wc_vars = ConfigVariables.objects.filter(type='Major Site')
        context = {
            'SConfigVariables' : sc_vars,
            'WConfigVariables' : wc_vars,
        }
        return mark_safe(render_to_string(self.template_name, context))


class VariableForm(forms.ModelForm):
    variables = forms.CharField(widget=TemplateVariablesWidget, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ConfigVariables
        fields = "__all__"
```

admin.py

```
class ConfigTemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  
    list_display = ('device_name', 'date_modified')
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        #extra_context['include_template'] = '/path/to/template.html'
        extra_context['include_form'] = VariableForm
        return super(ConfigTemplateAdmin, self).change_view(
            request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context,
        )
```

change_view.html

```
{% block extra_content %}
    {% if include_template %}
        {% include include_template %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if include_form %}
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ include_form.as_p }}
    </form>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

page that is loaded:
[image: sample of issue]

Comment: but your form (`VariableForm`) includes all fields (`fields = "__all__"`) so obviously with `{{ form.as_p }}` it'll show input fields for all the fields of your model.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to display data in a table, and also have a hidden(?) form where they can add a new entry of the data displayed in the table. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure this one out. I added an include data option and sent it through to the template as per the below:

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    from sites.models import ConfigVariables
    config_variables = ConfigVariables.objects.all()
    extra_context = extra_context or {}
    extra_context['include_data'] = config_variables
    extra_context['include_template'] = 'admin/config_variables.html'
    #extra_context['include_form'] = VariableForm
    return super(ConfigTemplateAdmin, self).change_view(
        request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context,
    )
```

then in the template

```
{% for d in include_data %}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your intentions in your template, you want to include your template **or** include the form. If that is the case:

```
{% if include_template %}
    {% include include_template %}
{% elif include_form %}
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ include_form.as_p }}
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

Another possibility, is that you do not want to `extra_context['include_form'] = VariableForm` in your `ConfigTemplateAdmin` class and you can create a different view (or method in your current view) for adding new Variables with your form!

Comment: I think i know what i want now, just having trouble with my dev env at the mo so can't test...